# How to update accounts & contacts from public forms without destroying existing data

Tags: data, form, design-patterns, architecture

We have Form Assembly forms publicly available on the internet which are working well. Within these forms, we collect a lot of data about our clients (350+fields). We want to bring that data into Salesforce automatically. Initially, I wanted to update existing accounts and contacts with some of the data collected. However, I realise now this could lead to existing/high quality data being updated incorrectly. For example, if a form is set to search for existing accounts before updating them, if the new form data is incorrect or blank, it will overwrite the existing data. Equally, I do not want to create new contacts and accounts as this may create duplicates.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before? If so, how was it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your two requirements are in conflict, the only solution is probably this:

The form submits data into custom staging objects (not the final accounts and contacts).

You build automation to match the staging records to existing accounts and contacts.

Your users review the staging records and correct any conflicting data points between staging and existing.

You build more automation to merge the staging records into the final accounts and contacts.

Comment: Thanks for your input David, yes that could work.

Answer (score 0):

For updating accounts & contacts from public forms without destroying existing
data following steps are included-

1- Click on Setup, enter Data Import Wizard in the Quick Find box, then click
Data Import Wizard.

2- Click Start Wizard!

3- Under "What type of data are you importing?" click Accounts & Contacts.

4- In "What do you want to do?" select the desired action.

5- If you're updating existing accounts, select Update Existing Records and
make sure Update Existing Account Information is also selected.

6- Choose the criteria for "Contact Match By" and "Account Match By".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Satrang Update Client Details ExchangeApp,

Using this app customers can update their Lead or Account & Contact info through an easy-to-use web form. Once the information is received, your salesforce user can quickly examine and Approve Lead or Account & Contact details with a single button click. and it will be instantly saved in the Actual lead or Account & Contact Record.

A significant time saver to keep your data up-to-date.

AppExchange Link - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsATUAZ&tab=e

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Satrang Update Client Details ExchangeApp.